# Remove CDATA from the input

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I get a string which has CDATA and I want to remove that.

```
Input : "<Text><![CDATA[Hello]]></Text><Text><![CDATA[World]]></Text>"
Output I want : <text>Hello</text> 
              <text>World</text>
```

I want to take all data between `<text>` and `</text>` and add it to a list.

The code I try is :

```
private List<XElement> Foo(string input)
{
    string pattern = "<text>(.*?)</text>";
    input = "<Text><![CDATA[Hello]]></Text><Text><![CDATA[World]]></Text>" //For Testing
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var a = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()).ToArray();

    List<XElement> li = new List<XElement>();
    XElement xText;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        xText = new XElement("text");
        xText.Add(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a[i]));
        li.Add(xText);
    }
    return li;
}
```

But, Here I get output as :

```
<text>&lt;![CDATA[Hello]]&gt;</text>
<text>&lt;![CDATA[World]]&gt;</text>
```

Can anyone please help me up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you shouldn't be using a regular expression at all. Instead, construct a valid XML document be wrapping it all in a root element, then parse it and extract the elements you want.

You *also* want to replace all CDATA nodes with their equivalent text nodes. You can do that before or after you extract the elements into a list, but I've chosen to do it before:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "<Text><![CDATA[Hello]]></Text><Text><![CDATA[World]]></Text>";
        string xml = "<root>" + input + "</root>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var nodes = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().ToList();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            node.ReplaceWith(new XText(node.Value));
        }
        var elements = doc.Root.Elements().ToList();
        elements.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But If I want to return List<XElement> then how can I do that ? Or how can I return just var ?

Comment: @Hello: `elements` is just a variable of type `List<XElement>`. You can return it as normal.

Comment: I want to change the Text to text, how can I do here, even though I pass Text, it should consider text

Comment: @Hello: Then you should do research on renaming elements in XML using LINQ to XML... I'm sure there are other questions about that on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XDocument instead of Regex:

```
var value = "<root><Text><![CDATA[Hello]]></Text><Text><![CDATA[World]]></Text></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(value);
Console.WriteLine (doc.Root.Elements().ElementAt(0).Value);
Console.WriteLine (doc.Root.Elements().ElementAt(1).Value);
```

Ouput:

Hello
World